# samsung mirrorlink certificate issue

Tags: android, xml, adb, samsung-mobile, mirrorlink

I have rooted note 9 android 10.
I received instructions from a friend to fix the samsung mirror link certificate as below:

```
 /data/data/com.samsung.android.app.mirrorlink/shared_prefs/Certs_Fetched.xml
/data/user/0/com.samsung.android.app.mirrorlink/shared_prefs/Certs_Fetched.xml
```

There may still be a user_d folder. Assign rights.

```
chmod -R 660 /data/data/com.samsung.android.app.mirrorlink/shared_prefs/Certs_Fetched.xml
chown system: system /data/data/com.samsung.android.app.mirrorlink/shared_prefs/Certs_Fetched.xml
chmod - R 660 /data/user/0/com.samsung.android.app.mirrorlink/shared_prefs/Certs_Fetched.xml
chown system: system /data/user/0/com.samsung.android.app.mirrorlink/shared_prefs/Certs_Fetched.xml
```

Certs _Fetched. Xml is this:

```
 <map>
<boolean name = "cert_stored" value = "true" />
</map>
```

but he does not want to help me om how to do it.

My question is:
1-how to create Certs_Fetched.xml and how to add it to
/data/data/com.samsung.android.app.mirrorlink/shared_prefs
and give it permission as above
2- in my phone /data/user/0/ I dont hav
com.samsung.android.app.mirrorlink/shared_prefs I do not know if I need to add the folder
thanks if you can help me